# Location permission dialog prompts lots of time in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

in iOS 10, sometimes when install the app, location permission prompts opens lots of time and hangs all app and not able to move further.

here is my code that works before iOS 10

```
-(void)startLocationManager{  
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    if (self.myCurrentLocation==nil) {
        self.myCurrentLocation=[locations lastObject];
        [[WALocationManager WALocationSharedInstance] checkLatestLocation];
    }
    else{
        if (self.myCurrentLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0){
            return;
        }
        self.myCurrentLocation=[locations lastObject];
        if([[WALocationManager WALocationSharedInstance] currentLocation]!=self.myCurrentLocation ){

        }
    }
}
```

In my plist file,

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app will use your location to get most nearyby activity around you.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app will use your location.</string>
```

Comment: where you called this startLocationManager

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in appdelegate .. didlaunch

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: remove from there and add in some class and try once

Comment: sorry its not a demo project .... its work in iOS 9 but in 10 sometimes prompts this much and cant handle by app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok I'll check that

Comment: Check the Authorization Status before you call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization `

Comment: Your `locationManager` it's a `strong` property?

Comment: @TonyMkenu yes ... `@property(nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Given video link is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of iOS 10, you should start your location updating only if the permission was granted, you should also check if the permission is already granted before requesting permissions:

```
-(void)startLocationManager{
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    // Check for current permissions
    [self checkLocationAuth:[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    [self checkLocationAuth:status];
}


-(void)checkLocationAuth:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;
            // did not ask for permission, ask now
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            } else { // iOS < 8? implicitly request permission
                [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }
            break;
        // Also need to handle failures, etc
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try this

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try below checks and see if it helps:

Do not call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` every time.

check for both `locationServicesEnabled` and `authorizationStatus`, call for `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` only if `authorizationStatus` is `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` and `locationServicesEnabled` return `false`.

Like,

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
   if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    }
}
```

Hope it will help:)

Comment: ya sure .. I'll try this too and check if it helps .. thanks