# iOS Unreliable Location Permission Alert

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, permissions, geolocation, alert

In our app we ask for location permission (WhenInUse) on one view that is used to display a map.

If the user choses to disable device location service (i.e. globally disabled in device settings) and then opens our view in the app, the location permission popup will show. Rinse repeat a few times (turn service back on, go on app, leave app, turn service off, etc.) and after a few times the location permission alert will stop showing.

Anyone know if this is a bug in iOS (happens on iOS 10)?

We could use our own alert that shows when

```
CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled = NO
```

but since we have no control about if/when the iOS location alert pops up, it sometimes happens that they both would show at the same time which is bad UX.

Any known solution to the problem? I have to explain to our QA and manager if this is a bug in iOS.

EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)negotiateLocationServicePermission:(UIViewController *)context
{
    /* Device location service is enabled. */
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        /* App location service is already authorized. */
        if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
            || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
        {
            /* App location service is authorized. Start location updates ... */
            [self startUpdatingLocation];
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            /* App location service not yet authorized and status is not determined (aka: first time asking for permission). */
            if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
            {
                /* Request the location permission from the user. */
                if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
                    [self requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; /* iOS 8+ */
                else
                    [self startUpdatingLocation]; /* iOS 7 */
                return YES;
            }
            /* App location service not authorized and previously denied. */
            else
            {
                /* App location service permission was denied before. */
                // Show custom alert!
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Device location service is disabled. */
    else
    {
        // Show custom alert!
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a bug, this is different AlertView.

If the user accept the location permission once, it's saved, it won't ask him again. But if the location service is disabled, this is a different case scenario.

You can implement it this way :

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

    NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied"     
                                           message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                          delegate:nil 
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

So if the user disables the location service from the Settings, the alert view can make a redirection to the Settings page.

This way multiple AlertViews won't show up. It just depends how you want to handle every case scenario like :

- Location service enabled in Settings but permission denied for this App
- Location service enabled in Settings and authorized permission
- Location service disabled in Settings

Make sure you handle every case, and test it out.

I don't know if I answered your question precisely, I hope it will help for your implementation.

Comment: My method is implemented in a similar way, checking for locationServicesEnabled but it doesn't work. You can see my code which I added above. Even though my method should take care of all cases and make sure that the iOS location permission alert only shows in case of kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined it also appears when I try to only show my custom alert. And I don't call requestWhenInUseAuthorization anywhere else.

Comment: Actually I observed the same erratic permission alert behavior on Google Maps app. Seems after all that this is either expected iOS default behavior or a bug in iOS.

Comment: @BadmintonCat That's weird, your method seems to handle every cases. But I still don't think this is an iOS bug. I found this post maybe it will help, but I'm sure you already checked it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695201/location-permission-dialog-prompts-lots-of-time-in-ios-10.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the iOS dialog is only issued when `authorizationStatus` is `undetermined`.
if the status is `denied` (when only the specific app is denied or the entire location service is disabled) you need to issue your own dialog with a deep link to settings